# IIS does not list a web site that matches the launched URL

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I have sharepoint 2013 application deployed on IIS. When I want to start debugging, I face this error:

> "Unable to start debugging on the web server. IIS does not list a web site that matches the launched URL".

I found a few solutions for this issue, but none work for me. The solutions I found:

1. VS should be running as Administrator. I did that.
2. Windows Authentication should be enable on IIS. I did that.
3. 'IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility' should be turn on in the Windows features. I did that.

How do I start debugging in Sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Please make sure IIS is running

Comment: most of the times, restarting iis and or visual studio helps.

Comment: I have some problem. Always solve not help me (

Comment: Restarting the visual studio worked for me, our project always requires to be run in admin mode.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try to start Visual Studio under administration account by choosing `Run as administrator`.

Comment: The OP has already tried that `1. VS should be running as Administrator. I did that.`

Comment: Answer was helpful for me before, and now again with VS17 :)

Comment: I don't really consider this a truly helpful answer, because there are better solutions. Still looking for it. Yes this does fix the problem for me, but on old work machine I didn't have to do this. So surely there is a more permanent, less "remember to always run VS in administrator" solution.

Comment: @Jared Right click on your VS shortcut -> properties -> shortcut -> Advanced -> run as administrator

Comment: Double check VS is running as admin - I had mine to always run as admin and it somehow disabled this option. Re-enabled

Comment: Follow @Jared's instructions and practice using your shortcut to launch VS instead of launching the .sln from file explorer.

Answer (score 4):

If nothing works as above said solutions , try this out

1. Start >> Control Panel >> Click Programs
2. Click Turn *Windows features* on or off.
3. In the User Account Control dialog box, click Continue
4. Expand Internet Information Services, expand Web Management Tools, and then expand IIS 6 Management Compatibility
5. Click to select the **IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility check box**, and then click OK.

Comment: Not all Operating systems have this. This is most certainly not the correct answer for me.

Comment: My OS had this, but it was still ineffective.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem.

I was trying to move my solution to a different DEV server of mine, that I don't use that often.

1.) I had not installed some of the items from the Application Development (duh, right) sections of the IIS Role Services.  I ended up checking everything, but I think you only need ASP.NET

2.) I installed the asp.net and web tools 2013  [available by clicking here](http://www.asp.net/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

++ you may need to have IIS rewrite module (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: You should add some details to explain how to do this without needing to read the link